# PyQtGraph 3D features

Tags: python, qt, object, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I started using `PyQtGraph` to build a `3D` interactive environment. I am able to add some grids, move the camera, and zoom in and out of the scene.

I need more features. For example, 3D object-picking to make the scene interactive; 3D objects/model imports, so I can import objects I build with 3D modeling programs; and other features like light control.

Does PyQtGraph currently support any of these features or will it at some point?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not the purpose of [PyQtGraph](https://www.pyqtgraph.org/): «It is intended for use in mathematics / scientific / engineering applications», so, data visualization, graphs, etc. If you want the kind of features you're listing, the only thing PyQtGraph could help you with is by studying its source code to understand how it does what it does; beside that, you need to do some research and studying on OpenGL and Python alone (possibly in conjunction with PyQt).

Comment: Thanks, I'm already studying those.